# How to embed page from CSP-restricted domain in extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I'm trying to develop a simple Chrome extension to display a page from a CSP-restricted google domain, in a popup opened on click. What is the simplest way to embed the page?

The page I am trying to embed has a Content Security Policy (CSP) that disallows `frame-ancestors`, so an `<iframe>` of the page won't work. Specifically, the page is the Google Tasks sidebar: https://tasks.google.com/embed/?origin=https://mail.google.com&fullWidth=1

A basic version of the extension would look like this:

## manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Google Tasks",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/tasks-19x19.png",
    "default_title": "Google Tasks",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
"permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "notifications",
    "tabs",
    "http://tasks.google.com/",
    "http://mail.google.com/"
  ]
}
```

## popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>   
      <iframe src="https://tasks.google.com/embed/?origin=https://mail.google.com&fullWidth=1"></iframe> 
  </body>
</html>
```

This example leads to this error in console (because of the CSP)

```
Refused to display 'https://tasks.google.com/embed/?origin=https://mail.google.com&fullWidth=1' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://mail.google.com".
```

I understand I could intercept the CSP ([as referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737818/refused-to-load-the-script-error-in-chrome-extension)) and overwrite the frame-ancestors property but I wonder if there is a better way to embed this page I'm trying to embed?

Comment: You can spoof the header as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15534822/). Some sites would fail though as they also check in JS for `window==top`

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, I successfully spoofed/blocked the CSP and x-frame-options in the header, but as you suggested, the [page](https://tasks.google.com/embed/?origin=https://mail.google.com&fullWidth=1) I'm trying to embed loads a javascript that cancels its own request. Appears it has its some other frame-busting tricks.